# Ошибка в терминале при запуске ассемблера nasm

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile, nasm

Решил изучить ассемблер под Linux, написал простейший тестовый код, выводящий всем известную строку. Затем, написал *Makefile* для сокращения возни с терминалом. Содержимое *Makefile*:

```make
all:
nasm –f elf $(source) 
ld –m elf_i386 –s –o $(source) $(source).o 
rm $(source).o
```

Но при попытке запуска выдаёт ошибку

```
nasm –f elf hello.asm
–f: fatal: more than one input file specified: elf
```

которая, как я понял, возникает из-за неправильного формата файла, но как исправить, я не знаю.

Comment: можешь нормально отформатировать содержимое `Makefile`'а как он есть? (серая кнопочка [edit] находится внизу сообщения)

Comment: @Fat-Zer не форматируеться по нормальному :(

Comment: Ну т.е. текст внутри блока кода Markdown сыпется?

Comment: @user409986, хотя бы скопируй с переводами строк и отступами... ЗЫ: у тебя тире (`–`) вместо минусов (`-`) только в сообщении или в самом файле тоже?

Comment: @donRumata я хз что подразумевается под "сыпется", потому скажу что он не разделяется на строки

Comment: @Fat-Zer хз ... это тип один и тот же символ ... вроде бы

Comment: @user409986, нет, они разные... и сама ошибка у тебя скорей всего как раз отсюда: `nasm` видит, что ему на вход подали три файла `–f` `elf` и что-то, во что разворачивается переменная `$(sources)` и не может это переварить.... других ошибок в файле куда больше, чем я могу перечислить, так что я дам просто ссылку на [одну из статей](https://habr.com/ru/post/423077/) из гугла, где есть сносный пример `Makefile`'а...

Comment: кароч https://support.typora.io/Markdown-Reference/#fenced-code-blocks